# Handle exception in do statement

Tags: shell

Please, I am trying to create the below script:

```
..
do
PID=$(echo $i | cut -d: -f1)
THREADS=$(cat /proc/$PID/status | grep -i "Threads" | awk '{print $2}')
done
..
```

But sometimes, there are processes that do not have such file **status** created.
So, how can I handle such exception as I am getting this message while executing the script

$ ./check_memory.sh
cat: /proc/9809/status: No such file or directory
$

So, I need to print this message as follows:

```
Memory Usage Per Process
----------------------------------------
PID       THREADS                                              
9936      129                                                       
9809      There is no status file for this process
```

Appreciate your support!

Appreciate your support, please

Comment: Check if `/proc/$PID/status` exists first, and if not set variable `THREADS` to `There is no status file for this process`?

Comment: Exception handling is not a feature shells have. There's no such thing as an "exception" here.

Comment: BTW, quite aside the question here, think about `threads=$(awk '/[Tt]hreads/ { print $2 }' /proc/${i%%:*}/status)` -- no need for any `echo | cut` since `${i%%:*}` expands to `$i` with everything after the first `:` removed, no need for `cat` or `grep` since `awk` can do everything they do.

Comment: That said, are you sure that there really isn't a `status` file for a still-existing process? More likely the process just exited before when you ran `ps` and when you're trying to read its state, so the whole `/proc/*` directory doesn't exist anymore as a whole. You can make the race smaller by double-checking inside the loop that the PID still exists, but you can't eliminate it: it's still possible for a process to exit between the check and when `cat` or `awk` or whatever else you have doing the read actually runs.

Comment: And if it's correct that the process genuinely doesn't exist anymore, you can just skip it -- do a `continue` in the loop and you're done.

Comment: FYI, there's no such thing as a `do` statement; `do` is a keyword that marks the beginning of the body of a `for` or `while` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `sh` script:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat<<EOF
Memory Usage Per Process
----------------------------------------
PID     THREADS
EOF

for pid in 999 $$; do
    threads=$(awk '/Threads/{print $2}' "/proc/$pid/status" 2>/dev/null) ||
    threads='There is no status file for this process'
    printf '%b\n' "$pid\t$threads"
done
```

### Output:

```
Memory Usage Per Process
----------------------------------------
PID       THREADS
999       There is no status file for this process
345234    1
```

### Edited script from question in comments

```
#!/bin/sh

printf "%-10s%-10s%s\n" "PID" "THREADS"

function sysmon_main() {
    pids=( $(ps -o pid ax | awk 'NR>1') )
    for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
        threads=$(awk '/Threads/{print $2}' "/proc/$pid/status" 2>/dev/null) ||
        threads='There is no status file for this process'
        printf "%-10s%-10s%s\n" "$pid" "$threads"
    done
}
sysmon_main | sort -bnr -k2
```

Comment: I tried it but seems there is a wrog syntax

Does this work my below code, please?


```
printf "%-10s%-10s%s\n" "PID" "THREADS"
function sysmon_main() {
RAWIN=$(ps -o pid,user,%mem,command ax | grep -v PID | awk '/[0-9]*/{print $1 ":" $2 ":" $4}')
for i in $RAWIN
do
PID=$(echo $i | cut -d: -f1)
THREADS=$(cat /proc/$PID/status | grep -i "Threads" | awk '{print $2}')
printf "%-10s%-10s%s\n" "$PID" "$THREADS"
done
}
sysmon_main | sort -bnr -k3  
```

Comment: Check edited snippet